# Keras multiple input model fails to match inputs from generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm completely new to Keras and AI. I have Keras 2.9 with Python 3.8.10 under Ubuntu 20.04. I have a 2-input model which uses synthetic data generated by a C++ function. I call the C++ function using Pybind11. The function returns an 512 by 512 grayscale image and a number. I give these alongside a generated parameter number to the model, the 2 numbers in a vector with repetitions. Training the model gives this error message:

```
[INFO] training model...
Epoch 1/10
2022-08-22 18:36:27.276873: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1733] INVALID_ARGUMENT: TypeError: `generator` yielded an element that did not match the expected structure. The expected structure was ((tf.float32, tf.float32), tf.float32), but the yielded element was [[array([0.47688578, 0.47688578, 0.53283023, 0.53283023]), array([[0.56156078, 0.56156078, 0.56291341, ..., 0.64667391, 0.64674161,
        0.64741869],
          ...,
       [0.42745098, 0.43529412, 0.41568627, ..., 0.48235294, 0.45882353,
        0.45098039]])], array([0.64286654])].
```

While printing model branch inputs and outputs (see code below) gives this:

```
KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 4), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'")
KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 512, 512, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_2'), name='input_2', description="created by layer 'input_2'")
KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 4), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='dense/Relu:0', description="created by layer 'dense'")
KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 4), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='activation_5/Relu:0', description="created by layer 'activation_5'")
```

The code is:

```py
def generate(aBatchSize:int=32, aRepeatParameter:int=2):
  dim = (512, 512)
  paraShape = (aRepeatParameter * 2,)
  def generator():
    xParameter = numpy.empty(paraShape, dtype=float)
    xImage     = numpy.empty(dim, dtype=float)
    y          = numpy.empty((1), dtype=float)
# populate variables
    xImage = randomLandscape(dist, height, tempAmb, tempBase) # Pybind11 call
    for i in range(1, aRepeatParameter):
      xParameter[i] = xParameter[0]
      xParameter[aRepeatParameter + i] = xParameter[aRepeatParameter]
    y[0]          = (tempBase - tempAmb) / 5
    yield [[xParameter, xImage], y]    # This was already yield {"parameters": xParameter, "image": xImage}, y -- no luck
  
  dataset = tensorflow.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator,
    output_signature=(
      (tensorflow.TensorSpec(shape=paraShape, dtype=tensorflow.float32, name="parameters"),
      tensorflow.TensorSpec(shape=dim, dtype=tensorflow.float32, name="image")),
      tensorflow.TensorSpec(shape=(1), dtype=tensorflow.float32, name="y")
            ))
  dataset = dataset.batch(aBatchSize)
  return dataset

def createMlp(aRepeatParameter:int):
  vectorSize = aRepeatParameter * 2
  inputs = Input(shape=(vectorSize,))
  x = inputs
  x = Dense(vectorSize, activation="relu")(x)
  return Model(inputs, x)

def createCnn(): 
  filters=(8, 4, 2, 1)
  inputShape = (512, 512, 1)
  chanDim = -1
  inputs = Input(shape=inputShape)
  x = inputs 
  for (i, f) in enumerate(filters):
    x = Conv2D(f, (3, 3), padding="same")(x)
    x = Activation("relu")(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim)(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
  x = Flatten()(x)
  x = Dense(16)(x)
  x = Activation("relu")(x)
  x = BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim)(x)
  x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
  x = Dense(4)(x)
  x = Activation("relu")(x)
  return Model(inputs, x)

repeatParameter:int = 2
mlp = createMlp(repeatParameter)
cnn = createCnn()

print(mlp.input)
print(cnn.input)
print(mlp.output)
print(cnn.output)

combinedInput = Concatenate(axis=1)([mlp.output, cnn.output])
x = Dense(4, activation="relu")(combinedInput)
x = Dense(1, activation="linear")(x)
model = Model(inputs=[mlp.input, cnn.input], outputs=x)

opt = Adam(learning_rate=1e-3, decay=1e-3 / 200)
model.compile(loss="mean_absolute_percentage_error", optimizer=opt)

batchSize = 32
model.fit(landscapeGenerator.generate(batchSize, repeatParameter), validation_data=landscapeGenerator.generate(batchSize, repeatParameter),
  epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=10, validation_split=0.3,
  use_multiprocessing=True, workers=2)
```

Comment: this is a bit too much code, please learn to debug... first thing you have to do, is to isolate the problem... for example, test your C++ function call from python, if you see that it works fine, then just ignore it, it's worthless polluting the question with additional complexity (and do the same with the rest, until you don't fine the source of the problem)

Comment: I've already stripped the code to the level I'm lost. There may be some lines less in the CNN part, but that's not much. The C++ part works, even when called from Python, that's why there is not a single line C++ in the post.

Comment: have you tested the C++ code? yes, does it work? 1)yes: remove it from the question, 2) no, then post an answer on that (AKA, make a MINIMAL reproducible example)

Comment: I don't think we understand each other. I've already written in a comment that the C++ part does work. Could you please show me where do you see a single line of C++ on this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out my generator function was no real Python generator. Here is the correct form:

```
def generate(aBatchSize:int=32, aRepeatParameter:int=2):
  dim = (512, 512)
  paraShape = (aRepeatParameter * 2,)
  def generator():
    while True:
      xParameter = numpy.empty(paraShape, dtype=float)
      xImage     = numpy.empty(dim, dtype=float)
      y          = numpy.empty((1), dtype=float)
# populate variables
      xImage = randomLandscape(dist, height, tempAmb, tempBase)
      for i in range(1, aRepeatParameter):
        xParameter[i] = xParameter[0]
        xParameter[aRepeatParameter + i] = xParameter[aRepeatParameter]
      y[0]          = (tempBase - tempAmb) / 5
      yield ((xParameter, xImage), y)

  dataset = tensorflow.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator,
    output_signature=(
      (tensorflow.TensorSpec(shape=paraShape, dtype=tensorflow.float32),
      tensorflow.TensorSpec(shape=dim, dtype=tensorflow.float32)),
      tensorflow.TensorSpec(shape=(1), dtype=tensorflow.float32)
            ))
  dataset = dataset.batch(aBatchSize)
  return dataset
```